# get a DHCP server's IP

Tags: linux, bash, ip, server, dhcp

I wanted to get the IP of my DHCP server into a bash variable.

like : `IP="192.168.1.254"`

I know this IP can be found in */var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases* or in */var/log/syslog* but I don't know of to extract it and put it in variable during my script (bash)

**EDIT:** file *dhclient.leases* look's like

```
lease {
  interface "eth0";
  fixed-address 192.168.1.200;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 192.168.1.254;
  option dhcp-lease-time 7200;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.254;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.1.254;
  option host-name "bertin-Latitude-E6430s";
  option domain-name "laboelec";
  renew 1 2015/02/16 10:54:34;
  rebind 1 2015/02/16 11:53:49;
  expire 1 2015/02/16 12:08:49;
}
```

I want the IP from line `option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.1.254;`.

Comment: post the content of those file which you want to extract, only one or two lines after and before the main line will do.

Comment: You didn't say what OS you're using and on my Linux Mint 17.1 the `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases` file is empty even though my network adapter is using DHCP and what are you going to do if/when the `/var/log/syslog` file has rolled over and doesn't yet contain any networking information.

Comment: Is the string `option dhcp-server-identifier` unique in the file?

Comment: I didn't know that `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases` could be empty !

Comment: `option dhcp-server-identifier` isn't unique. Here by "chance" there is only "eth0" interface but it could have "wlan0" interface too which contain  the same structure of lines.

Comment: So what would make that line unique?

Comment: Can you add shell scripts to `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/` ?

Comment: If there is only one connection this line is unique, if you try to connect a second time it will create a new `lease{...}` @Jahid . 
Yes I can, I have root privileges @Mark Plotnick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To more compatibility I finally opted for a simple solution which is to send the IP server like a string on broadcast every seconds. For that I use socat (because netcat can't send message to braodcast)
my DHCP server run this script in background:

```
#!/bin/bash
interface="eth0"
IP=$(ifconfig $interface  | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}')
Broadcast=$(ifconfig $interface  | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f3 | awk '{ print $1}')
Port="5001"

while [ true ];
do
    sleep 1
    echo $IP | socat - UDP4-DATAGRAM:$Broadcast:$Port,so-broadcast
    #to listen: netcat -l -u $Broadcast -p $Port
done
exit 0
```